# AsyncStorage in react native

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

```
componentDidMount(){

    console.log("get")
    AsyncStorage.getItem('token')
                    .then((res)=>{
                console.log(res)    
            })

}
```

I have componentDidMount with console.log and AsyncStorage.getItem function.I want to make axios call after getting the token value.
But the thing is AsyncStorage.getItem is not working **get** `//console.log('get')` is printed as log without res.
Any help please how to get value? am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I would start by adding a .catch() .method to your promise chain to see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: @ mattdevio I added .catch() now but no error is printed in that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it as follows.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.onGetToken();
}
onGetToken = async () => {
    try {
      const token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('token');
      console.log("get")
      // call api using axios with token value
    } catch(e => console.info('error for getting token', e))
}
```

Comment: If the `getItem()` method returns a promise then both your code and his are identical in terms of behavior.

Comment: that's why we use `await` keyword.

Comment: Which is why your code won't solve his problem. Its the same functionality.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think the current token value is null or undefined.

Comment: Thats possible.

Comment: @Ilnur Yalaletdinov nothing is printed :-(

Comment: @Ilnur Yalaletdinov i add console.log() out side try and catch and only that is printing.

Comment: @Ilnur Yalaletdinov i don't know why but when i close my app on phone and then again run my code it is printing values.

Answer (score 0):

Try to Just restart the app and asyncStorage will behave properly.